# Причина большого кол-ва выданных данных Angular 4

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular4

Всем доброго дня! Ребят пишу на Angular 4 с использованием WebSocket-ов, и не могу догнать,какова может быть причина того что когда я отправляю запрос с методом и параметрами, то в консоле он выдает ответ дублирующийся неоднократно.Пробовал гуглить неоднократно, задавая разные вопросы, но ничего путевого не выдало.Кто сталкивался?Скриншот прилагается.[image: Дублирующиеся ответы с сервера]

Comment: Приведите ваш код. И тот который на сервере, желательно, тоже.

Comment: Код запроса привести?

Comment: Скорее всего, потому что вы подписываетесь на получение данных и не отписываетесь при уничтожении элемента. Или потому что компонент, который подписывается используется несколько раз на странице.

Comment: Кстати да, я вроде не отписываюсь, и значит может быть если я буду отписываться то такого быть не должно я так понимаю?

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что все это дело просходит еще и в `DoCheck`

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался с данной проблемой)Проблемка была из за моей забывчивости делать unsubscribe(отписку) :)